# How to properly mark designer code for code metrics to ignore it

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I marked all instances of InitializeComponent with

```
<CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("WinForms Designer", "")>
```

So those will not show up during code metrics analysis. The rest of the generated code is still considered mine, particularly setters and getters for each control. Marking the whole partial class (the winforms designer part) with GeneratedCode makes the whole class disappear from code metrics, so even my custom logic. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Metrics does not ignore Form classes on purpose see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx

> Code generated for Windows forms is not ignored, because it is code
>   that the developer can see and change.

Perhaps the [Code Metrics Viewer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9f35524b-a784-4dbc-bd7b-6babd7a5a3b3) extension will do what you want.

Comment: Setters and getters for controls are something I cannot see nor change, so when I click on them in Code Metrics Results, nothing happens. It appears that Microsoft have problems with logic sometimes. I'll try the alternative you suggested and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Installed, had some issues down the road, got those solved, now it's those two famous errors, CA0055 and CA0052, on my main project. Two other projects in a solution passed the analysis, but I don't need it there. I'll try to get some help from developer.

Comment: Yeah, not saying the decision to not ignore Form classes was good thing, just that they do.  Code Metrics and Code Analysis are two different features.

Comment: In Code Metrics Viewer by Matthias Friedrich you click _Analyze Solution_ to obtain _code metrics_. I agree it should have been called _Calculate Code Metrics_ to comply with Visual Studio wording.

Comment: It appears I had <PropertyGroup><PostBuildEvent></PostBuildEvent></PropertyGroup> (an empty PropertyGroup) in my project file, which kept Code Metrics from working properly. Now 43K lines of code, up from 14K. Looks like Code Metrics Viewer ignores GeneratedCode attribute on InitializeComponent. So the situation is worse than with Microsoft built-in tools.