# InitializeComponent() in Code Maintainability index

Tags: c#, maintainability, code-metrics

Why does the function InitializeComponent in form constructor has a very low maintainability index in Visual Studio C#?

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

In some of my forms it goes as low as 9 or 16 score.

Comment: Does it also get marked as duplication because you have other forms? Which maintainability index are you using? Is it the visual studio inbuilt one? And have you looked up the algorithm thats used to calculate it?

Comment: I'd ignore it. `InitializeComponent` is generally all auto generated. Its score is irrelevant.

Comment: @nldev yes, the one built into the Visual Studio and could not find what algorithm exactly it uses

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I am ignoring it and the whole score, but just out of curiosity, I want to know why Visual Studio is basically giving itself such low score since it generated this code.

Comment: Generated code is not meant to be maintained by a human. Ignore its score whatever it is and any metric related to it (that's probably [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12306263/1997232)).